# Java recoloring BufferedImage not working with an image of a larger height

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedimage

I have a program that is supposed to take the RGB values of an image and then multiply them by some constants, and then draw the new image on a JPanel. The problem is that if my image is over a certain height, specifically over 187 pixels,  the new colored image is different than an image with a height of less than 187px.

The JPanel shows this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHZes.png).

Notice how the longer recolored image is different than the shorter one. I'm sure that the shorter image's colors are correct, and I have no idea how it's getting messed up.

```
public class RecolorImage extends JPanel {
public static int scale = 3;

public static BufferedImage walk, walkRecolored;
public static BufferedImage shortWalk, shortWalkRecolored;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(200*scale, 400*scale);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new RecolorImage());

    walk = ImageLoader.loadImage("/playerWalk.png");
    walkRecolored = recolor(walk);  
    shortWalk = ImageLoader.loadImage("/playerWalkShort.png");
    shortWalkRecolored = recolor(shortWalk);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
    g.scale(scale, scale);  
    g.drawImage(walk, 10, 10, null);
    g.drawImage(walkRecolored, 40, 10, null);
    g.drawImage(shortWalk, 70, 10, null);
    g.drawImage(shortWalkRecolored, 100, 10, null);
}
```

The recolor method:

```
public static BufferedImage recolor(BufferedImage image) {
    BufferedImage outputImage = deepCopy(image);

    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {

            int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
            Color c = new Color(rgb);

            int r = c.getRed();
            int g = c.getGreen();
            int b = c.getBlue();

            r *= 0.791;
            g *= 0.590;
            b *= 0.513;

            int newRGB = (rgb & 0xff000000) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            outputImage.setRGB(x, y, newRGB);
        }
    }

    return outputImage;
}
```

How I load the images and make deep copies:

```
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static BufferedImage deepCopy(BufferedImage image) {
    ColorModel colorModel = image.getColorModel();
    boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    WritableRaster raster = image.copyData(null);
    return new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
}
```

My original images: the [tall image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kILgV.png) and [short image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMBRG.png). Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source images have different color models:

- the short image uses 4 bytes per pixel (RGB and alpha)
- the tall image uses 1 byte per pixel (index into a palette of 256 colors)

Your recolored images use the same color model as the source images (thanks to the `deepCopy` method), therefore the recolored image for the tall image also uses the same color palette as the source image, meaning that it cannot contain all the colors you want.

Since your recoloring code overwrites each pixel of the output image anyway the deep copy operation is unnecessary. Instead you would better create a full color image as target image like this:

```
public static BufferedImage recolor(BufferedImage image) {
    BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    //... code as before
}
```